# REST Service - What should be used? Retrieve account information via POST or pass encrypted account number and use GET?

Tags: rest

A colleague and I were having a discussion around what is the best approach to get account history information from backend server.

The account identifier, which is sensitive information, is passed as part of the request.  In response, the the account history is returned.  We have an option to either encrypt the account identifier and pass it as a parameter into a GET request.  Second option is that we make it part of the body of a POST request.

If we use GET request, it is proper use of REST verb since we are 'getting' history from server.  If we use POST request, it hides the sensitive information from the server logs but its (not?) the proper use of REST since POST should be used to create or update resources and not retrieve them?

What is the proper way to handle this scenario?  Encrypt the account identifier and use GET? or use POST and send the account identifier in the body?  Is it fair to say that if sensitive information is involved, always use POST?

Comment: is the sensitive information represented by the actual account identifier, or by what could be retrieved through it (aka the response)?

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu, The account identifier and the content of the response is sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

how would you GET other sensitive info?  many systems use token-based authentication, where an active session is assigned a token authenticating just that session, which may be passed either via standard GET querystring or in many cases added as a custom HTTP header which the server then checks before allowing access.

here's [some useful REST api auth methods](http://restcookbook.com/Basics/loggingin/)

Answer (score 0):

IMO the cleaner coding style according to REST would be to put it in the URL (encrypted) and use GET.

For security reasons I would prefer putting it into the content of a POST request and use SSL to encrypt the request content.

The get approach has an additional downside: The URL is logged in clear text (Router, providers, etc.). Any person with the logged URL that has access to the target system could simply copy paste the URL in a browser and get the sensible data (even if the account identifier was encrypted) unless no further authentication system is used.